# Is there a way to look up results of a case in the United Kingom just by having the case number?

Tags: england-and-wales, legal-research, case-law

I recently found a case on law360 that I want to know the outcome of.
In the article, they mentioned the following information:

- case number (HT-2021-000213)
- High Court of Justice of England and Wales

I tried the search on [www.judiciary.uk/court/high-court](http://www.judiciary.uk/court/high-court), but without success.
How do lawyers usually get this information when it could be relevant for a new case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That usually isn't the only information you have.

For example, when I searched for HT-2021-000213 on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=HT-2021-000213) I found [this law360 article](https://www.law360.com/articles/1393161), which I guess might be the same as the one you have read. It's behind a paywall, but I can access enough of the article to see this text:

> The case is Twitch Interactive Inc. v. Viewers Labs Ltd. and others,
> case number HT-2021-000213, in the High Court of Justice of England

Using the party names (e.g. Twitch Interactive v Viewers Labs), it is possible to search most *reported* cases using a legal database such as Westlaw or Lexis (note that these are subscription based services). Many cases (including many *unreported* cases) also appear on [Bailii](https://www.bailii.org/), which is free.

You can also call the court, give the case reference number, and ask for more information e.g. the party names, whether the case has been decided, the outcome, a copy of the transcript (probably for a fee).

Comment: Thanks a lot, really appreciate the reply.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to JBentley's answer, and for general interest, LawSE has a Meta [community wiki](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261/online-legal-references) faq which lists a number of free and paywall sites - including [casemine](https://www.casemine.com/judgments/uk?locale=en_UK).

Unfortunately, there is no trace of the judgement sought by the OP - possibly because the citation indicates the action was brought in 2021 and the case has not yet been finalised.